# rsync seems like copying files but it doesn't actually

Tags: rsync

I used rsync like below. There is no error and it seems like copying files (I can see file names on the sending list) but there is nothing in the target directory. I want to send files from 115...***:/home/juna/demo to /media/volume1/juna/demo.

```
rsync -avz -e "ssh -p #### 115.***.***.***:/home/juna/demo" /media/volume1/juna/demo
```

the result is this (hshs.txt is in 115...***:/home/juna/demo)

```
sending incremental file list
drwxrwxr-x          4,096 2019/10/09 01:44:17 demo
-rw-rw-r--              0 2019/10/09 01:44:17 demo/hshs.txt

sent 88 bytes  received 132 bytes  440.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

With that syntax should mean list all files in /media/juna/volume1/demo. Also the rsh command ( `-e` ) part looks wrong and should not work even if remaining line had correct syntax so generally best to avoid syntax if not needed.
Try:
`rsync -avz -e "ssh -p #### %H" 115.***.***.***:/home/juna/demo /media/volume1/juna/demo`
Instead if You really need -e because of possible non-default port